# Should I use map or iterate in EarthEngine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm working with Earthengine with a commercial license now so I started worrying about the performance of my computations. As the caching mechanism is preventing me from doing performance checks on my own, I'll ask it here and maybe a GEE developer will pass by.

Should I prefer using `map` or `iterate` when looping on a collection?

```py
sequence = ee.List.sequence(1000) 

# map version 
featureList = sequence.map(lambda i: ee.Feature(point, {"id": i}))

# iterate 
featureList = sequence.iterate(
    lambda i, l: ee.List(l).cat(ee.List([ee.Feature(point, {"id": i})])), 
    ee.List([])
)
```

In this example, I would of course go for the `map` for readability but there are more tricky situations where forcing myself to think with `map` is taking more time than a good old `iterate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what you're really trying to do, but there are no situations where you can use both map and iterate where you should choose iterate.  You should also [avoid converting to list](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_converting_to_list_unnecessarily) when possible..

Also, using the profiler should turn off all caching.

Comment: thanks for your answer, here is a small test my colleague sent me where we didn't saw any diff between the 2 profiled processes: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8ce62db02a2768eecc12c6ccbb50da8d

Comment: Those examples are so small that the normal noise is probably 50% of the expense, however the mapped version is clocking in at about 30% cheaper EECUs.  If you did this by ~1000x then you might have numbers that are believeable.

Comment: Thanks @NoelGorelick for your answer. I have a follow up question (I don't think it's enough to be a new thread by itself): profiler turns off all caching also in python?

Comment: Yes.  It's a backend flag.